# 3 editText & textWatcher problem in android

Tags: android

Dear All I need help in this issue,
I am working on a small App to insert it as a part of anther App, in this App there are 3 `EditText` number1, number2, & number3.. i need to make the summation of `editText` number 1 & 2 to be reflected in number3 `editText` without clicking button, also in the same time if number1 & number3 values available number2 will be the sum (without button)...
I made if statement to send the `editText` to the `textWatcher`, the App is running perfectly for the numbers below 10, once the numbers increased to more than 10, the App will take the second `editTextvalue` as integer with one digit only (in this case the 10th number only)
[image]

please find the JAVA code

```
    private EditText number1;
    private EditText number2;
    private EditText number3;
    Button reset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number1=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
        number2=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_2);
        number3=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_3);
        reset=findViewById(R.id.reset);

//=========== to reset the editText
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String dx = number2.getText().toString().trim();
                number1.getText().clear();
                number2.getText().clear();
                number3.getText().clear();
            }
        });

//======== if statement to add Edit Text 1 & 2 to text watcher
        if(number1.getText().toString().equals("") && number2.getText().toString().equals("")){
            number1.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
            number2.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
        }
//======== if statement to add Edit Text 1 & 3 to text watcher 2
        if(number1.getText().toString().equals("") && number3.getText().toString().equals("")){
                number1.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher2 );
                number3.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher2 );
        }


    }

//=========== TextWatcher when EditText 1 & 2 are used & EditText 3 is empty...
// ==========the value of EditText3 will be the sum of EditText 1 and 2
    private TextWatcher loginTextWatcher  = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!number1.getText().toString().equals("") && !number2.getText().toString().equals("")){

                if(number3.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString().trim());
                    Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString().trim());
                    number3.setText(String.valueOf(value1+value2));
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

//=========== TextWatcher when EditText 1 & 3 are used & EditText 2 is empty...
// ==========the value of EditText2 will be the sum of EditText 1 and 3
    private TextWatcher loginTextWatcher2  = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!number1.getText().toString().equals("") && !number3.getText().toString().equals("")){

                if(number2.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
                    Double value3 = Double.parseDouble(number3.getText().toString());
                    number2.setText(String.valueOf(value1+value3));
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

}
```

please somebody advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Thanks for everybody helped in this, I finally find a good solution & the App is working as I wanted
1- I removed the unnecessary if statement as advised by **Shay Kin**
2- I added `editText`1 since it is common between all the calculation methods to the `watchListener` the two of them.
3- I removed the if statement in the `onCreate` method & replace them with `setOnFocusChangeListener` for `editText`2 & 3... in this I have to remove the opposite `editText` from its `textWatcher` to avoid freezing in the App. the code i added is

```
//=========== this is to add editText 1 to the textWatchers for the two condition by default
        number1.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
        number1.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher2);
//=========== this ti set the focus of editText 2 and send it to the related textWatcher
        number2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    // must remove editText 3 to from its textWather to avoid App freezing
                    number3.removeTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher2);
                    number2.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);

                }

            }
        });
//=========== this ti set the focus of editText 3 and send it to the related textWatcher
        number3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    // must remove editText 2 to from its textWather to avoid App freezing
                    number2.removeTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
                    number3.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher2 );
                }
            }
        });
```

also in the `textWatcher` the if condition should be adjusted from

```
if(!number1.getText().toString().equals("") && !number3.getText().toString().equals("")){
```

to

```
if(!number1.getText().toString().equals("") && number3.hasFocus()){
```

because if you kept the first condition and used the `textWatcher` for `editText` 1 & 2 twice (or several times) & then you used the arrangement 1 & 3 the App will freeze.